# htaccess only for some pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi
I use apache geo-ip and I want to allow users from other countries only to pages such as:

```
[http:]//[www.]my_domain/forum/

[http:]//[www.]my_domain/forum/viewforum.php?f=

[http:]//[www.]my_domain/forum/viewtopic.php?f=
```

It is possible with htaccess?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved here](http://scripturi-instalare-ubuntu.blogspot.com/2011/11/tribul-apache-este-atacat-cum-il-ajutam.html):

```
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE RO AllowCountry

<FilesMatch "^ucp.php|posting.php|memberlist.php">

    Order Deny,Allow

        Deny from all

Allow from env=AllowCountry

Allow from localhost

ErrorDocument 403 /errors/500.php

</FilesMatch>
```